# get textbox Array from asp.net mvc generates page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

My problem is that i have a dynamic loop in which i generate 5 textboxes and now i need get the data of each index because i want to send by in a array to the controller. Can anybody tell me how i get the values from the textbox arrays. All textboxes have the same name and id but they have an index.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should NEVER have multiple elements with the same ID.  If you want, they can all have the same CLASS though.

**UPDATED to reflect clarified requirements.**

However, to solve your issue, you can try this:

```
$("#yourformID").bind("submit", function() {
   var groups = new Array();

   $("textarea").each(function(i, el) {
      name = $(el).attr("name");
      index = $(el).attr("index"); // Is 'index' an attr?
      if (groups[name] === undefined) {
         groups[name] = new Array();
      }
      groups[name][index] = $(el).val();
   });

   // You can now insert the array as the value of the submit button...
   $(this).find("input[type=submit]").val(groups);
   return true;
});
```

I'm not sure what you meant by 'index', but if that is an attribute on the textarea, then this should get you close.

Of course, on the server-side, you'll need to de-compose the array of arrays, but at this point each item should be easily referenced by name and index.

Good luck!

Comment: He talks about his controller, so I guess this isn't a clientside issue.

Comment: He also tagged this jQuery. So I think it is?

Comment: My Problem is that i have not only one textbox in my loop. I have 5 text textboxes for each time the loop get passed and i need one array with these 5 values and then i need an array of these Arrays to pass them to my controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over `HttpContext.Request.Form.AllKeys` in your controller like:

```
foreach(var key in HttpContext.Request.Form.AllKeys) {
    if(key.StartsWith("textboxname")) { // key will look like textboxname[1]
        // value is in
        var val = HttpContext.Request.Form[key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just follow
[the haacked explanation on binding to collections](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)

and create your inputs the right way
now need to further parse it at the client side